# Integral and Wick rotation (Srednicki ch75)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, wick-rotation

I was reading chapter 75 of Srednicki's QFT book and I   ran into this statement.

*To determine the value of its integral, we
make a Wick rotation to euclidean space, which yields a factor of i as
usual; then we have*
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{d^{4}l}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{\partial}{\partial l^{\beta}}f_{\alpha}(l)=i\lim_{l\rightarrow\infty}\int\frac{dS_{\beta}}{(2\pi)^{4}}f_{\alpha}(l)
\end{equation}
*where $dS_{\beta}=l^{2}l_{\beta}d\Omega$ is a surface-area element, and $d\Omega$ is the differential
solid angle in four dimensions.*

I don't understand how the LHS of the equation can be written as the RHS. Especially, how did the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial l^{\beta}}$ disappear? Can someone give me a detailed explanation?

Comment: It seems OP is asking about the 4D version of the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. OK so he's using the divergence theorem, but how though? If the the form of LHS was 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial l^{\beta}}f_{\beta}(l)
\end{equation}
instead of 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial l^{\beta}}f_{\alpha}(l)
\end{equation}
then I can use divergence theorem I guess, but in this case can I?

Comment: $f_\alpha(\ell)$ is not an arbitrary function here, but given by Eq (75.38). So this is not a general statement. Is it correct for the given function?

Comment: Yes $f_{\alpha}(l)$ is not an arbitrary function. It is
\begin{equation}
f_{\alpha}(l)\equiv \frac{l_{\alpha}}{l^{2}(l+p+q)^{2}}
\end{equation}
to be specific. It must be correct at least for this specific function, otherwise it means that the book is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Prof. Srednicki first performed the Wick rotation and then used a version of the 4-dimensional divergence theorem.

Given the comments below the question, people are unaware of the "component-wise" divergence theorem, so I'll give a derivation below starting from the typical expression of the divergence theorem.

We have $$\int dV\:  \nabla \cdot \vec A  = \int dS\: \hat n \cdot \vec A $$ from the typical divergence theorem in d-dimensions. Now consider an $\vec A = \vec c f$ where $\vec c $ is a constant vector. This yields, using the usual product rule for derivatives,

$$\vec c \cdot \int dV\:  \nabla f  = \vec c \cdot \int dS\: \hat n f $$

This is true for any $\vec c$, including the unit basis vectors, so we have

$$\int dV\:  \nabla f  = \int dS\: \hat n f. $$

Note that the above is a vector equation that holds componentwise:

$$\int dV\:  \partial_\mu f  = \int dS\: n_\mu f. $$

This is true for any $f$, so it is true for e.g. functions $g_0, g_1, ..., g_d$, which we can write as

$$\int dV\:  \partial_\mu g_\nu  = \int dS\: n_\mu g_\nu. $$

Please let me know if you need any clarifications or if that addressed the heart of your question. I beleive that should answer where the derivative goes on the right hand side of your equation. All the functions above are assumed to be well-enough behaved.

Comment: That explains it very clearly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @embreakin If you're satisfied with the answer, please consider hitting the green checkmark under the vote count to mark the answer as accepted. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer for some more details about what it means to accept answers.